# restore idle screen session under FreeBSD

Tags: gnu-screen

I use GNOME desktop environment under FreeBSD. I had multiple tabs in GNOME terminal 2.26 and in each tab I had an ongoing `screen`(4.00.03) session. I logged into one of the remote servers with SSH and `cat` a large file and after a while, the `screen` session in GNOME terminal tab hanged. Output of `pstree` looks following:

```
$ pstree -p 1700
-+= 00001 root /sbin/init --
 \-+- 01506 martint gnome-terminal
   \-+= 01586 martin bash
     \-+= 01699 martin screen
       \-+= 01700 root screen
```

There are dozen of processes under PID 1700, which all, including PID 1700, are in idle state:

```
$ ps -p 01700 -o command,state
COMMAND          STAT
screen           Is  
$
```

I have disconnected the SSH session to remote server and also checked that the `screen` scrolling is unblocked. Is there a way to restore this `screen` session?

Comment: sysutils/tmux is a great screen alternative.

Comment: Maybe, but unfortunately it does not help to restore this idle `screen` session :)

Answer (score 2):

You can issue detach before re-attaching from another terminal, e.g.:

```
$ screen -list
$ screen -d -r ...
```

Comment: I tried `screen -ls` from another terminal and it lists this idle screen session as "Attached". Now if I try to detach this screen with `screen -d 1700.pts-0` from another terminal, then looks like `screen -d 1700.pts-0` hangs and if I trace the system calls of this with `truss -fp 23137`(23137 is the PID of `screen -d 1700.pts-0` command) from jet another terminal as a root user, then all I receive is a `23137: SIGNAL 17 (SIGSTOP)` and truss shows no additional output.

Comment: @Martin, then you can try to send a `SIGCONT` to pid 23137 - and then try the remotely-detach/reattach sequence again.

Comment: I tried to detach this idle `screen` session named `1700.pts-0.` multiple times, but unfortunately it does not detach. It simply stays with its `Is` state which according to FreeBSD `ps` manual means that process is idle(sleeping for longer than about 20 seconds) and process is a session leader.